# Check if calendar is primary

Tags: android, android-calendar

I retrieve all calendars with:

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
            null, null, null, null);
```

The cursor contains all calendars that I use. 
According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#IS_PRIMARY) the cursor should contain a column that indicates if the calendar is the user's primary calendar. 
Yet

```
cursor.getColumnIndex("isPrimary");
```

returns `-1`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on some more phones and it seems that on some phones there is no IS_PRIMARY column. So you should not rely on this field. The phone it did not work with was an HTC Sensation XE. On Nexus-phones (Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 5) it was present.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and the IS_PRIMARY column is still not present on the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the same on a Google Nexus 7 Tablet with Android 5.1.1.
The result was, there is a column in the cursor without an alias for isPrimary. Its name is instead

> COALESCE(isPrimary, ownerAccount = account_name)

I am now checking if the column index is -1 for isPrimary and if so I use the above name for the column.

I still don't know why this happens, but it seems to be a missing alias in the implementation on some devices.